VersionedTransaction issue
I'm trying to do quick swap with solana actions and Jupiter swap API V6. My goal is to swap sol to usdc. Once in a while it works with the same code. As well the simulation goes well. As you can see below I have got the VersionedTransaction transaction from quote-api and event try to rebuild this transaction with addressTableLookups but in the and I have got an error:
Error: Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved
at MessageV0.getAccountKeys (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.esm.js:1025:13)
at TransactionMessage.decompile (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.esm.js:2072:33)
at prepareVersionedTransaction (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/actions/lib/esm/createPostResponse.js:48:83)

export async function swap(account: PublicKey, connection: Connection): Promise < VersionedTransaction > {

const coinToAddress = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v";
const coinFromAddress = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112";
const amountToSwap = 1000000000;

const quoteResponse = await (
    await fetch(`https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=${coinFromAddress}&outputMint=${coinToAddress}&amount=${amountToSwap}&slippageBps=50`)).json();

console.log(quoteResponse)

const transaction = await (
    await fetch('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            quoteResponse,
            userPublicKey: account.toString(),
            wrapUnwrapSOL: true,
        })
    })
).json();

const { swapTransaction } = transaction;


const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
var versionedTransaction: VersionedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);

const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

// get lookup table
const atls = versionedTransaction.message.addressTableLookups.map(address => address.accountKey)
const atlsAccount = await Promise.all(
    atls.map(async (alt): Promise<AddressLookupTableAccount> => {
        const account = (await connection.getAddressLookupTable(alt)).value;
        if (!account) {
            console.log("Could not retrieve address lookup table", alt.toBase58());
            exit(42);
        }
        return account;
    })
);
console.log(atlsAccount)

const decompiledMessage = TransactionMessage.decompile(versionedTransaction.message, { addressLookupTableAccounts: atlsAccount });
decompiledMessage.payerKey = account
decompiledMessage.recentBlockhash = blockhash

const newVersionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
    decompiledMessage.compileToV0Message(atlsAccount)
);

console.log(newVersionedTransaction);

console.log("---------------------------------simulation----------------------------------------------------");
const simulation = await connection.simulateTransaction(newVersionedTransaction)
const tx =  await connection.sendTransaction(newVersionedTransaction)
console.log(simulation)

return newVersionedTransaction;
}

